# Chance that a group of $n$ people collectively have a missing birthday.

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins, birthday

Suppose there is a city with $n$ residents, what is the probability that there is some day in the year at which none of them have their birthday?

In other words, suppose we divide $n$ balls into $k=365$ (no leap year exceptions) boxes, what is the probability that there is some empty box?

From some references similar to [this one](https://mathandtcs.wordpress.com/2019/06/05/distinct-and-non-distinct-balls-and-bins/) I derived that this probability can be approximated by:
$$1 - \frac{k! S(n, k)}{k^n}.$$
Where $S(n,k)$ denote the Stirling number of the second kind.
This formula is close to some brute force approximations so I figured it is correct.
However, with $n=5000$ and $k=365$ the probability came out negative, which does not seem right.

Does anyone know the true probability for this problem and/or a way to calculate it?
Or can anyone give me a hint to where I went wrong?

Comment: The formula $1-k!S(n,k)/k^n$ should not give a negative number. What program did you use  to calculate this? I assume that its a floating point error. This Mathematica code computes the value correctly: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z9PwVbB1MDAwJorG8gyNjO15iooyk8Csg0VdBWCSzKLcjLz0oONovN0FLJjFbQUshUV9BWy4/KsuQKKMvNKov2iQepjY///BwA "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online") (takes 12 sec to run).

Comment: The Coupon Collector's Problem is relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

@MikeEarnest was totally right!!

I computed the value for $S(n,k)$ using the method from the link I provided, however they do not provide the correct method for computing Stirling numbers.

Using a correct method to calculate Stirling numbers of the second kind I indeed get positive probabilities.
I assume that these probabilities are correct since they are close to my brute forced answers.

In conclusion, the formula I gave above is correct.